# Paste from advanced filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck on a line and don´t know how to solve the error. I´m dividing the lines in a list by filtering different names with an advanced filter and copying the data in individual sheets, but got stuck on a line, the last one before the Next: "newWS.Range("A1").Paste". I get error 1004 from debugging:

```
Private Sub loopfilter()

Dim thisWB As Workbook
Dim filterws As Worksheet
Dim howto As Worksheet
Dim advfilter As Range
Dim Postenws As Worksheet
Dim VersandRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Name As String

Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set filterws = thisWB.Sheets("Filtro")
Set howto = thisWB.Sheets("How to")
Set advfilter = filterws.Range("A1:AK2")
Set Postenws = thisWB.Sheets("Alle gemahnten Posten (2)")
Set VersandRange = howto.Range("J2", Cells(Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp))

Dim newWS As Worksheet

    For Each rng In VersandRange
        filterws.Range("AK2") = rng.Value
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Postenws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                                                          CriteriaRange:=advfilter, _
                                                          CopyToRange:=filterws.Range("A5"), _
                                                          Unique:=False
        filterws.Range("a5").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Set newWS = thisWB.Sheets.Add
        newWS.Name = rng.Value
        newWS.Range("A1").Paste
    Next

End Sub
```

Any idea why its not working?

Thanks

Comment: Try switching the order around - add the sheet; name the sheet; copy the range from `filterws`, then immediately do the paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (also made a sheet reference to your definition of Versandrange). Paste is not a method of the range object.

```
Private Sub loopfilter()

Dim thisWB As Workbook
Dim filterws As Worksheet
Dim howto As Worksheet
Dim advfilter As Range
Dim Postenws As Worksheet
Dim VersandRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Name As String

Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set filterws = thisWB.Sheets("Filtro")
Set howto = thisWB.Sheets("How to")
Set advfilter = filterws.Range("A1:AK2")
Set Postenws = thisWB.Sheets("Alle gemahnten Posten (2)")
Set VersandRange = howto.Range("J2", howto.Cells(Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp))

Dim newWS As Worksheet

For Each rng In VersandRange
    filterws.Range("AK2").value = rng.Value
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Postenws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                                                      CriteriaRange:=advfilter, _
                                                      CopyToRange:=filterws.Range("A5"), _
                                                      Unique:=False
    Set newWS = thisWB.Sheets.Add
    newWS.Name = rng.Value
    filterws.Range("a5").CurrentRegion.Copy newWS.Range("A1")
    filterws.Range("a5").CurrentRegion.clearcontents
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip SJR, can you explain your changes so that I can understand? The copying part works, unfortunatelly the filter doesn´t: it doesnt change the value in -- filterws.Range("AK2") = rng.Value

Comment: I've put the copy and paste on a single line (and you do not need to specify the paste - it is implied in this syntax). The only other change I made was to fully qualify VersandRange. I don't see how anything I did could affect your loop, though you should probably clear the data on filterws after each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I´ve added this line to the end --  filterws.Range("AK2").Clear  After the first iteration of the loop only the A column is copied. The rest remains unchanged from the first fiter.

Comment: I didn't mean that range. I've amended the code above. Step through your code and see what value rng takes as you go through the loop.

Comment: Now I understand. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it